# Drupal 7: Randomize header background passing file name from template.php to the css file

Tags: php, css, variables, header, drupal-7

My scenery: I have Drupal 7 with a Omega theme installed.

My issue: I have to set a random background for a specific zone of my css (section-header). 
I have 4 separated css files because of the responsive design, and the file name is the same but the only difference is the _mobile _narrow _normal _wide postfix. 
I have set the background in the css file with some simple lines:

```
#section-header {
  background: url(../images/sf_header_wide.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  height: 390px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}
```

I need to add more than one image for the background, and I would like to know if there was possible to import the file name from an external source (my template php file for example) and obtain something like this without adding the background lines to the template.php file, because i have separated css files for the responsive design

```
#section-header {
      background: url("../images/<?php echo $fileimage; ?>_wide") no-repeat;
      height: 390px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;  
    }
```

Is it possible to obtain what i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend doing it this way as web browsers are going to be caching your CSS files so if you want it to change each time, it will not. Besides that, this is not a normal practice,

There are a few things you could do instead, though.  One would be within the page header itself, just generate that style sheet like so

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="primaryStyleSheet.css" media="screen" />
[...]All other head stuff, imports, responsive style sheet stuff here
<style>
/* Define this style AFTER the other CSS files are imported to be sure it loads */
#section-header {
  background: url("../images/<?php echo $fileimage; ?>_wide") no-repeat;
  height: 390px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}
</style>
</head>
```

Additionally, you could add `!important` to each of CSS definitions (ie. `height: 390px !important;`)